# peer to peer software vpn solutions?

Tags: vpn, nat, openvpn, hamachi

Looking for a software based way to create a vpn for sales guys that will automatically reconnect if dropped (setup pptp dialin for moment but doesnt autoreconnect).

I'm aware of Hamachi which is perfect but the guy doesnt want to spend $200/year on the commercial version and i dont like the idea of him cheating.

The next option I know of is openvpn, but that's not as straight forward to configure on machines out in the field already.

Any other options available you can think of, free or one time fee based ones?